Is it possible to replace the horizontal slider to a vertical slider in a ListAnimate?
My screen is always wider than taller, and the animations from ListAnimate always stop if the horizontal slider created by ListAnimate is not visible. Is there any way to change that horizontal slider to a vertical slider (that continues to play and behaves as the horizontal one)? My guess is that it is impossible, but you are always surprising me...
So far, I've tried to use a combination of ControlPlacement -> Left, and ControlType -> VerticalSlider, but although the control looks as I want it to look, the animation does not play (probably because the change hides the play and stop controls next to the slider). I've also tried asking Copilot (Microsoft's AI), but its answer involved recreating the whole ListAnimate function by using a Manipulate (I can't do that either, as far as I know, as I need to play the contents of a Table which are frames created with a VectorDensityPlot function, and I need to go to specific frames).
Any help or indication that you can give me would be much appreciated. And, even if you can't help me, thank you for reading all of this.
Edit:
David G. Stork asks for an example code. I cannot put here all the code used to create the animation, so I'll adapt the code created by Goofy (including what I tried). I hope this helps:
list = Table[Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, n], PlotRange -> 5], {n, 5}];
ListAnimate[list, ControlPlacement -> Left, ControlType -> VerticalSlider]

Edit 2:
The answer provided by Bob Hanlon also requires a horizontal Animator that has to be visible for the animation to run, and stops as soon as the Animator is hidden from view (for example, by scrolling the window). The same happens when trying to create a custom Manipulate. So, since the Animator must be visible at all times for the animation to run, and there is no VerticalAnimator, then I guess there is no way to do what I need.

Please give example code.

Note that list = Table[Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, n], PlotRange -> 5], {n, 5}]; ListAnimate[list] // InputForm shows that ListAnimate[] in effect creates a Manipulate to animate a list. Perhaps you could adapt it.

Thank you, Goofy! That could be the answer. I'll have to check. I thought someone could have already figured out the answer to my problem, that's why I asked. But I'll continue to investigate following your suggestion.

Following the suggestion given by Goofy, I analyzed the Manipulate and it seems that it uses an Animator; and since there is no VerticalAnimator, or a similar control, then there is no way to do what I want to do. At least, I can't find it.

lst = Style[#, 72, RandomColor[]] & /@ Range[10];

ListAnimate[lst,
 ControlPlacement -> Left, 
 Method -> {"ControlAreaDisplayFunction" -> (Rotate[#, 90  Degree]&)}, 
 Alignment -> Center]


Replace 90 Degree with -90 Degree to get:


You, kglr, are amazing!!!!! This is exactly what I was looking for! And your solution is so elegant and brilliant!! THANK YOU!!!!!

@RoberRM, thank you for the accept and kind words.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]

list = Table[Plot[Sin[n  x], {x, 0, 10}], {n, 5}];

Using Manipulate, click on the Manipulate menu (plus sign: Bookmarks/Autorun) and select Autorun to display the animation controls.
Manipulate[
 Show[list[[n]]],
 {{n, 1}, 1, 5, 1, Appearance -> {"Labeled"}},
 ControlType -> VerticalSlider,
 ControlPlacement -> Left,
 AutoAction -> True,
 TrackedSymbols :> {n}]



Thank you for your answer, Bob Hanlon! It does not answer my question (whether or not it is possible to keep the ListAnimate and only change the slider orientation), so I'll wait a little longer before accepting it, but it could be a solution if everything else fails.

Unfortunately, Bob Hanlon, your method still requires that the horizontal slider is in view so that the animation runs: as soon as the horizontal slider is hidden from view (by scrolling the window) the animation stops. Anyway, thank you for trying.
